# Change in PANDAS .to_csv default formats? Or is it Anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

Has anyone else noticed this change using Anaconda/pandas/python with WIN7?  I just re-ran a program I last ran about a week ago that calls .to_csv.

1) Date formats used to be:

```
'%#m/%#d/%Y %#H:%M' (5/1/2014 0:30)
```

but now are:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' (2014-05-01 00:30:00)
```

2) Also, logicals that used to print as:

```
FALSE, TRUE
```

now print as:

```
False, True
```

3) Finally (so far as I've noticed), pandas used to truncate floats to a few decimals but now I'm getting the full representation:

From: 1.498 to: 1.4980000000000002

I can deal with setting the datetime format in .to_csv but the other two are sure making file compares difficult and I'd hate to have to write something that changes them all.

I use Anaconda with PyCharm as my IDE. PyCharm will automatically update packages and I think it did.  Both the  32 and 64 bit versions show that the Anaconda\Lib folder was changed 6/5/2015.  In that folder, at the root,  profile.pyc was changed along with a couple others at the same time as well as the 'hotshot' folder (whatever that is).  Oddly enough, it doesn't look like pandas has changed since October.

So maybe it's something I did, or maybe not. The only thing that comes close is that I used .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") in a different function during the time this changed.

Does anyone know if there could be a profile setting somewhere that changed?  If so, how do I change it back?

Comment: I've seen pandas timestamps as `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` for a couple years or so. As for floats no longer truncating, that is definitely something I've noticed with the newer releases, and it is annoying. I can't say for your #2 since I never print booleans to a CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the info in a misery loves company sense.  Do you use Anaconda by any chance?  Since mine *just* changed it would be interesting to know why.

Comment: I use Anaconda, yes.

Comment: I bet that's it then. As above, profile and hotshot file modified timestamps changed but not pandas.  If I find time I might try to figure it out.